# Unity Рисование линий на UI

Tags: unity3d

Есть ли возможность в Unity рисовать стандартные фигуры на UI элементах, таких как Panel, Image и тд?

Answer (score 0):

Возможностями компонента [Line Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) всё, в принципе, и ограничивается.